# Flutter Authentication - MobX + GoRouter

Tags: flutter, authentication, mobx, clean-architecture, flutter-go-router

I'm building an app and I intend to use MobX, but I need some route manager so that if the user logs off, it is redirected to the login screen again.

However, the go_router package has a variable called refreshListenable, which receives a Listenable. How can I create a variable within MobX?

If not the best solution, what would it be?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSQvS.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6s0g.png)

I hope to be able to use AuthController to check user status and perform login or logoff.